# How to prompt user to enter which [row][column]

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want the user to enter which row and which column in order to read the data in it

for example if the user enter row = 6 column = 0, it will print out Pw1

```
    static String fullChessBoard[][] = {
    {"Rb1", "Kb1", "Bb1", "Qb1", "Ab1", "Bb2", "Kb2", "Rb2"},
    {"Pb1", "Pb2", "Pb3", "Pb4", "Pb5", "Pb6", "Pb7", "Pb8"},
    {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
    {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
    {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
    {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
    {"Pw1", "Pw2", "Pw3", "Pw4", "Pw5", "Pw6", "Pw7", "Pw8"},
    {"Rw1", "Kw1", "Bw1", "Qw1", "Aw1", "Bw2", "Kw2", "Rw2"},
    };

    System.out.println(Player1W + ", please make a move");
    int row = scan.nextInt();
    int column = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: Hi! Can you show us what you have tried so we can help?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what errors you are getting, so we can help. We aren't going to write code for you

Comment: here the sample code that I've do

Comment: I'm new to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloChess{
    static String fullChessBoard[][] = {
        {"Rb1", "Kb1", "Bb1", "Qb1", "Ab1", "Bb2", "Kb2", "Rb2"},
        {"Pb1", "Pb2", "Pb3", "Pb4", "Pb5", "Pb6", "Pb7", "Pb8"},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   ", "   "},
        {"Pw1", "Pw2", "Pw3", "Pw4", "Pw5", "Pw6", "Pw7", "Pw8"},
        {"Rw1", "Kw1", "Bw1", "Qw1", "Aw1", "Bw2", "Kw2", "Rw2"},
        };

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter Row: ");            
        int row = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Column: ");
        int column = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Result : "+fullChessBoard[row][column]);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this program you are writing is a command line program, where the user puts information into the command prompt and your program responds. If it's not, please let me know, as my answer operates under that assumption.

There's more than one way to get input from the command line in Java. The following link has a few great examples: 
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-to-read-input-from-console-in-java/][1]

Here's a quick example I chalked up that outputs the first repeated letter from a string the user enters, it uses the BufferedReader class set to get input from the System.in object wrapped by an InputStreamReader. I'm sure that sounds complicated, but the code explains it better:

```html
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class FirstRecurringCharacter {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
        String toAnalyze = reader.readLine();
        returnFirstRecurring(toAnalyze);  
    }
    
    private static Character returnFirstRecurring(String toAnalyze) {
        String toSearch = toAnalyze;
            Set<Character> seenCharacters = new TreeSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < toSearch.length(); i++) {
                if (seenCharacters.contains(toSearch.charAt(i))) {
                    System.out.println(toSearch.charAt(i));
                    return toSearch.charAt(i);
                } else {
                    seenCharacters.add(toSearch.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("No repeating characters.");
            return null;
    }
    
}
```

The .readLine() method gets the users input after they hit enter on the console. Try it yourself!

With your program, you might want to prompt them, one at a time, to insert a row index, then a column index, you can cast their input to integers if needed, and then use them in the remainder of the program. I hope this helps!